# Yarn workspace help needed

Tags: typescript, react-native, eslint, prettier, yarn-workspaces

So I am working on a react native project. And for the project my client after typing a lot of code asked me to add a late feature. Basically this was a very easy feature but because of all the code I wrote the feature became exceedingly hard to add. And because of this I decided to restart from scratch as my code could do an improvement and I also had a new design in mind the only problem is I need to install and setup all the packages all over again which is very painful as I need to go into the android folder and add some stuff too. Now after a few days of research I found yarn workspace and since I was already using yarn I thought let me use this as using this will help me install the packages for all my project in the root of the workspace, this also meant that I could setup ts-config and eslint for all the apps from the root so do it once happens every where.
now here comes the problem. Every video I looked at, every document I saw showed me either yarn workspace with react and react native, yarn workspace with react-native without typescript or just a blank node js server side template
And me being a beginner didn't know how to manipulate these docs and make the project work.
the final outcome I wanted was to have a yarn workspace with this kind of structure:

```
task-manager-workspace-> the workspace containing folder
  workspaces-> Kind of like the packages folder
     apps-> containing all the older and present versions of the app
        app-> the latest react native app(bare bone not expo) with typescript included
     common-> contains common stuff between the apps with not much changes
        core-> contains some js logic like saving data or receiving data
        views-> contains some common components like the header and navigation bar
```

now this whole application contains typescript should use eslint(preferably wcandillon configuring) and configured with prettier. 
I am not asking you to do the work for but as a person who just started learning about workspace just yesterday please tell me how I am supposed to do this very intricut setup on the yarn workspace.

Comment: Are you using Lerna or any monorepo management tool?

Comment: no because I dont know excactly what lerna does but if it helps then I am okay with it

Answer (score 2):

Basically you will need a `package.json` for each of your packages, including your root. In your root directory's `package.json`, you'll add all your workspace packages like this:

```
{
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "common-core",
      "common-views",
      "apps-app1"
    ]
  }
}
```

Maybe you could even nest the `core` and `view` package within another `common` package, I'm not entirely sure about that. Now in your respective subdirectories containing the packages, each package has its usual `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "common-core",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you then want to add a dependency to one of the packages, you can type:

```
yarn workspace common-core add <my-dependency>
```

in the root of your project and it will add the dependency to the respective workspace (package), possibly sharing it with other packages that have the same dependency. You can even have one workspace depend on another and efficiently share the same, always up-to-date code between various packages.

Unfortunately I do not know much about ts-config and eslint, maybe someone else can contribute on this topic.

Keep in mind though that even if the packages are all installed in the root of your project, you will still need to manage the dependencies of each package individually (as in add/remove whichever you want).

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. Thanks I will definitely try it. Just 1 question. In the views folder I have a header.tsx file which contains a react native component And so as you know a typescript site must be complied to JavaScript so what does the app do to the file? Does it compile it in the views folder itself or does it compile in the app after getting the file? Or does it just from an error in my face?

Comment: Also thanks alot for trying to answer the question as I thought no one would because of the review!

Comment: @KidCoder No worries! The transpiler that translates your TS into JS will have its own intermediary "build" folder where the results are temporarily stored. It will not modify your actual source code (.tsx). The app then is built from the generated JS, which will run on the device. If you had an error in your TS, the transpiler would tell you during build time, usually when you try to run the app.